# Improving my invoice generator

Tags: vb.net

In this function, the copy (`Write XML`) is inside, but I want it to be separated from the function.  How can I improve this function?

```
Sub ExporttoFolder(ByVal POSPath As String, ByVal dt As DataSet, ByVal FolderCopyto As String,ByVal SelectedItem As DataTable)

If MsgBox("Do you want to Export Invoice to " & _WhouseToComboBox.textBox.Text & " ? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

Dim Whouse As String
For Each dr As DataRow In SelectedItem.Rows
Whouse = dr.Item("whouseDesc")
ProcessCopy(POSPath, dt, FolderCopyto, Whouse)
Next dr
End If

End Sub

Sub ProcessCopy(ByVal targetDirectory As String, ByVal File As DataSet, ByVal FolderTarget As String, ByVal DirectoryFather As String)

Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
Dim Filepath As String = Nothing
Dim subdirectory As String

For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
Try

If Path.GetFileName(subdirectory) = DirectoryFather Then

If IO.Directory.Exists(subdirectory & "\" & FolderTarget) Then

File.WriteXml(subdirectory & "\" & FolderTarget & "\" & File.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID") & ".xml")

End If

End If

ProcessCopy(subdirectory, File, FolderTarget, DirectoryFather)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

Next subdirectory

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is `ProcessCopy` recursive? Can you give an example of what the folder structure looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this function, the copy (Write XML) is inside, but I want it to be separated from the function.

### Shallow Observations

In no particular order:

- **You need to *indent* your code**, it makes it much easier to read. Give that <kbd>Tab</kbd> button some lovin'!
- **Exceptions are like urine samples**: there's a lot of information in there to analyze if and when you need to, and the last thing you want to do is to swallow them.

---

### Separation of Concerns

I think both procedures do more than they claim. Let's break down what needs to happen:

- Prompt the user for confirmation, do nothing without user's consent.
- Get the names of all target folders.
- Find the destination folders.
- Determine the name of the file.
- Write the file.

#### Implementation

**Prompt the user for confirmation, do nothing without user's consent**

Asking for user confirmation before exporting stuff is probably a good idea. This doesn't mean the actual prompting needs to happen in the method that performs the actual export. Consider this:

```
Public Function GetUserConfirmation(ByVal prompt As String) As Boolean        
    Return (MsgBox(prompt, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
End If
```

Yes, it's a one-liner. That doesn't make it less of a useful function. We don't *really* care about `MsgBoxResult`, we just want to know if the user answered <kbd>Yes</kbd> to a question. This function *abstracts away* the `MsgBox` call and the need for knowing about `MsgBoxResult`, which makes it much more `If`-friendly - whether you're reading:

```
If GetUserConfirmation(confirmationMessage) Then
```

Or

```
If Not GetUserConfirmation(confirmationMessage) Then
```

You know exactly what's going on and you don't need to worry about how it's implemented.

Now in your code, this would translate to:

```
Sub ExportToFolder() 'parameters omitted
    If GetUserConfirmation(confirmationMessage) Then
    ' do all that stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

I think this is a bad construct, it *smells* like the code in the `If` statement is begging you to be surrounding a call to that method, so you can do this:

```
If GetUserConfirmation(confirmationMessage) Then ExportToFolder 'parameters omitted
```

And have `ExportToFolder` look like that:

```
Sub ExportToFolder() 'parameters omitted
    ' do all that stuff
End Sub
```

This means the logic that grabs an instance variable to come up with the prompt message is also moved outside of the method. Actually by doing this we have just separated the concerns of *coming up with a prompt message* and *prompting the user with some message*.

So we've got user confirmation. One down.

**Get the names of all target folders**

We have some `DataTable` that represents a *selected item* which contains a column called `"whouseDesc"` which is the name of the "parent" folder we want to use. Your code knows about a lot of things it doesn't need to be bothered with: in fact all this `DataTable` boilerplate just doesn't belong there. The method doesn't *want* a `DataTable`, it *needs* what's it in.

I would replace `SelectedItem As DataTable` with `TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String)`, it makes the intent much clearer: we need an enumerable bunch of folder names, and we're going to expect they're the names of subfolders of a target folder.

Reading the `DataTable` that contains the folder names is out of scope here.

The procedure now looks like this, notice how much more focused it's starting to be:

```
Sub ExportToFolder(ByVal POSPath As String, _
                   ByVal dt As DataSet, _
                   ByVal FolderCopyto As String, _
                   ByVal TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String))

    Dim subfolderName As String
    For Each subfolderName In TargetSubfolderNames
        ProcessCopy(POSPath, dt, FolderCopyTo, subfolderName)
    Next

End Sub
```

**Find the destination folder**

`ExportToFolder` takes the `POSPath` parameter only to pass it down to `ProcessCopy` at each iteration. It's the same folder every time you call `ProcessCopy`, and yet every time the method runs, you're fetching the subdirectories *and looping through all of them* every time, verifying if the target folder exists under that subdirectory. I'm exhausted, aren't you?

If each call to `ExportToFolder()` exports stuff into 1 file in 1 folder, then it's not exactly clear why you're looping directories here, why the method is recursive, and how you're coming up with the filename.

My guess is that you want to be sure you're writing to a directory that exists. That's fine, but if there's only 1 file to write to, you're over-complicating it.

**Determine the name of the file**

If I understand correctly, you know the full file name from the start, and given `InvoiceId` which is `dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID")` this would be your file name:

```
Path.Combine(Whouse, FolderCopyTo) + InvoiceId + ".xml"
```

So we can have a `GetExportXmlFileName` function that does it, and that can return an empty string if the folder doesn't exist:

```
Function GetExportXmlFileName(ByVal ParentFolder As String, ByVal TargetFolder As String, ByVal InvoiceId As String) As String

    Dim result = String.Format("{0}.xml", _
                   Path.Combine(ParentFolder, TargetFolder), _
                   InvoiceId)

    If Not Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(result)) Then result = String.Empty

End Function
```

Your method is starting to look like this:

```
Sub ExportToFolder(ByVal TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String), _
                   ByVal TargetFolder As String, _
                   ByVal Content As DataSet)

    Dim SubfolderName As String, FileName As String
    Dim InvoiceId As String = Content.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID")

    For Each SubfolderName In TargetSubfolderNames
        FileName = GetExportXmlFileName(SubfolderName, TargetFolder, InvoiceId)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) Then ProcessCopy FileName, Content
    Next

End Sub
```

**Write the file**

At this point I'm questioning the need for `ProcessCopy` altogether:

```
Sub ExportToFolder(ByVal TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String), _
                   ByVal TargetFolder As String, _
                   ByVal Content As DataSet)

    Dim SubfolderName As String, FileName As String
    Dim InvoiceId As String = Content.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID")

    For Each SubfolderName In TargetSubfolderNames
        FileName = GetExportFileName(SubfolderName, TargetFolder, InvoiceId)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) Then Content.WriteXml(FileName)
    Next

End Sub
```

Let's see, if we have 4 files to export, and the 2nd one blows up, we can't try the 3rd and 4th like this - we'll have an exception to **deal with** (read: not swallow).

```
Sub ExportToFolder(ByVal TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String), _
                   ByVal TargetFolder As String, _
                   ByVal Content As DataSet)

    Dim SubfolderName As String, FileName As String
    Dim InvoiceId As String = Content.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID")
    Dim Errors As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    For Each SubfolderName In TargetSubfolderNames
        FileName = GetExportFileName(SubfolderName, TargetFolder, InvoiceId)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) Then 
            Try

                Content.WriteXml(FileName)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Errors.Add(ex) 'fine, don't do anything with it.
                                   'at least you can break and inspect it.
            End Try
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This is where we can extract a method to wrap the `Try...Catch` block and, incidentally, the `Content.WriteXml` call - I'll pretend you want to log errors with an instance-level NLog logger:

```
Sub ExportToFile(FileName as String, Content As DataSet)
    Try

        Content.WriteXml(FileName)

    Catch ex As Exception
        _logger.ErrorException(FileName, ex)

    End Try
End Sub
```

This last refactoring has given its final shape to the `ExportToFolder` method:

```
Sub ExportToFolder(ByVal TargetSubfolderNames As IEnumerable(Of String), _
                   ByVal TargetFolder As String, _
                   ByVal Content As DataSet)

    Dim SubfolderName As String, FileName As String
    Dim InvoiceId As String = Content.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("InvoiceID")

    For Each SubfolderName In TargetSubfolderNames
        FileName = GetExportFileName(SubfolderName, TargetFolder, InvoiceId)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) Then ExportToFile(FileName, Content)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me :) , but i have one more question, you have miss declared "_Logger" => _logger.ErrorException(FileName, ex)

Comment: @AhmadAlHalabi That's always good to read! Thank *you* for the green tick!

Comment: :) no, thank you
but What about "_Logger" => _logger.ErrorException(FileName, ex)

Comment: I was refering to [this](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging/wiki/Using), but that's just what *I* would do - if you don't know what to do with an exception, at least log it :)